# Address already in use - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 3010 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gems

Запускаю проект:

```
rails s -p 3010
```

И получаю:

> /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:266:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 3010 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Притом я почти что уверен, что до этого вырубал проект сочетанием `Ctrl-C`. И это происходит уже не в первый раз за последние две недели.

Раньше проблему решал с помощью поиска и уничтожения по PID:

```
lsof -i tcp:3010 -t
```

Долгое время я не видел эту строку ошибки, но вот она снова вернулась. И на этот раз она походу "прокачала скилл" и на старую добрую команду:

```
lsof -i tcp:3010 -t
```

Ничего не возвращает. То есть теперь я не знаю как остановить процесс, на котором якобы уже запущен проект.

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` наше все:

```
sudo lsof -t -i:3010
```

Вывело все порты.